Статические фалы не подгружаются на удаленном сервере
Работаю с Джанго. Сейчас дошел до этапа подключения CSS (статических фалов). При запуске сайта на локальном сервере все подгружается и работает корректно, те стили работают. Как только я запускаю сайт на удаленном сервере весь CSS не работает.
Так выглядит вырезка из Settings
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    'sport/static/',
]

Прикрепляю структуру проекта

В шаблоне я подгружаю статические файлы:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>     {% block title %}  {% endblock %}    </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{%static 'sport/css/main.css'%}">
</head>
<body>
{% load static %}
    <aside>

        <span class = "logo">Green Protein</span>
        <h3>Навигация</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href=""><li>Главная</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'sport_home'%}"><li>Личный кабинет</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Про нас</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Контакты</li></a>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>



</body>
</html>

В файле url тоже об этом не забыл
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,  include

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,  include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('sport.urls')),
    #path('sport/', include('main.urls'))

]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


В документации ничего найти не смог, там описано только выше перечисленное.
